# Memories compatible with Samsung 4GB DDR3 PC3-12800 1600MHz

Tags: laptop, memory, compatibility

I need to upgrade my RAM. There are two slots. One of them is empty and the other one contains a RAM with the following spec:

> 4GB DDR3 PC3-12800 1600MHz

[image]

I am going to add another 4GB RAM to the empty slot. How can I make sure the other RAM I buy is compatible with this one and my motherboard? Here's my system info:

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Technical support request — Questions asking about troubleshooting hardware or technical support for hardware are off-topic for Hardware Recommendations because the site is here to provide pre-purchase hardware recommendations and to recommend hardware for a specific task, rather than to support existing devices. You may get help on Super User.

Comment: @Jeff This one I am not quite sure on.  To me, it falls in between a tech support request and a hardware recommendation request.  I would rather err on the side of being polite today (have been told I can be a bit snide).  Of course ArtOfCode can always crack the whip on me lol

Comment: Whip cracked, @NZKshatriya. No, but seriously, this is nearly there - at the moment, it's phrased as "how do I make sure it's compatible", which is a compatibility query and not in scope. If Meysam could [edit] this question to rephrase it as "recommend me some RAM that is compatible with X, Y, and Z, and also has these other things I want, for this price", that'd be okay.

Comment: Had a feeling that was coming

Comment: @NZNZKshatriya I agree.  ArtOfCode whipped me into shape a long time ago.  I err on the side of not getting lashes these days.  And my run to 1000 has been halted by the influx of on hold questions these days.

Comment: Personally, I'm not all that focused on reputation.  More on answering what I can when I can lol.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already had the exact way to find which DIMMs to use, you just didn't know it.

Go to whichever site you prefer to use to buy PC components, and search for DDR3 PC3-12800 1600Mhz, make sure to specify SODIMM (laptops) or DIMM (Desktops)

If you would like a recommendation:  I would suggest [G.SKILL F3-12800CL11S-4GBSQ](https://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820231481&ignorebbr=1)

Reasons being: This is a standard SO-DIMM for laptops.  27 USD on newegg, lifetime warranty from the manufacturer (I have been using G.Skill for over 10 years, only had one bad DIMM in a matching set, followed their RMA steps and had my replacement very quickly)

Comment: Thank you. Is the RAM you have suggested for laptops? Secondly, how do you say it should be 1600Mhz while the specification shows 800MHz => `Max BAndwidth PC3-12800 (800MHz)`

Comment: Well, I think that was my mistake in the title of the question!

Comment: @Meysam  I changed the answer to the laptop version of the memory